# How to fix webcam quality in skype

Tags: skype

I Skype Call a XYZ person, the person i am talking is not able to see my clear video. It's very dull & black. How can i fix it? The video quality is to bad. I also referred to this guide(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype) but no change the video is still the same. Following these instructions:

```
 uvcdynctrl -s 'Backlight Compensation' 7
 uvcdynctrl -cv
 guvcview -o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended steps to check the webcam quality are (This same problem happened to me for a Logitech webcam):

1. Test the webcam with another app (Cheese, Kamerka, Kamoso & guvcview). Guvcview and Kamoso are great since they offer many features for webcam that Skype does not. You can even test the webcam with Google Hangouts or http://www.testwebcam.com/
2. If the webcam works great in other apps or webapps, then you know the webcam is not the problem, but the software. We then go to test capturing methods with tools like `qv4l2`. You can check several webcam features with this. There are some capturing options that are limited to 5 fps. Others can go up to 30 fps and even other can get to 60 fps.
3. Last option is to update Skype with the latest version (or a version that works correctly). Is no secret that Skype has had a huge amount of video problems on Linux. From slow webcam, to black one, to crashing if you opened the webcam and more. For some users, using the Skype that comes with Ubuntu works great. For others you need to [download a newer version](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/). In my case in one PC it works perfect with the one that Ubuntu had. In another case, the upgraded version worked great. Currently I have the 4.2.0.13 Version.

NOTE: I also followed the steps you are doing and got no solution. A tip I would say is that Skype might crash and leave a zombie in memory, so you need to search for the Skype process and kill it before starting another Skype session. Just mentioning this in case it happens to you.

Comment: I have checked the webcam its working perfect...skype has some problem how should i fix it

Comment: Well like I said, you can either update the Skype version or opt for an alternative. This is one of the main reasons I do not choose Skype when doing conferences. Because any problem it has, I have to rely on Microsoft to fix it. Not very trusty on speed. You could go to the Skype forum, in the linux section. There is a small trick that might work for you or might not. Open another webcam app and use it for 30 seconds. Then close that app and open Skype. See if the webcam works. There isn't much to do to fix Skype issues in closed source. We are very limited.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you use `guvcview`?

While Cheese shows a pretty OK picture of my webcam, Skype does display a darker image. Then, after changing contrast and brightness on `guvcview` (without the `-o` option you can see a live preview of your video), the Skype video call stays exactly as it was setup on `guvcview`.